# How to setup the DHCP server?

Tags: networking, dhcp

I am new to networking. I have a FC16 machine that has two network interfaces em1 and p3p1.
The em1 is connected to the outside world. The p3p1 is the interface that I want to connect to my embedded board. I have configured p3p1 to a static ip address - here are the details. The problem is that the embedded device is not able to acquire the IP address sent out by the DHCP server. I cannot see the Discover, offer, request, and acknowledge messages also. What could be the issue here?

## gvim ifcg-p3p1

```
HWADDR=cc:b2:55:ba:b6:a4
BOOTPROTO=none
#IPADDR=10.0.0.1
#NETMASK=255.255.255.0
#NETWORK=10.0.0.0
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPADDR=10.0.0.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=10.0.0.1
PREFIX=24
```

Now, on ifconfig, it shows me this.

```
p3p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr CC:B2:55:BA:B6:A4  
          inet addr:10.0.0.10  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

I have given the extra parameters on the dhcp config file.

## gvim /etc/sysconfig/dhcpd

```
DHCPDARGS="p3p1"
```

Now, this is the dhcpd.conf file.

```
# gvim /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

#
# DHCP Server Configuration file.
#   see /usr/share/doc/dhcp*/dhcpd.conf.sample
#   see dhcpd.conf(5) man page


default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;

ddns-update-style none;

subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
     range  10.0.0.1 10.0.0.14 ;
}
```

However, on running the dhcp server-

as

```
#sudo service dhcpd restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  dhcpd.service
```

I see that there is no DORA - Discover, Offer, Request, Ack. procedure.

Messages from my embedded device.

```
CFE> ifconfig eth0 auto
External phy address 4
Auto-negotiation timed-out...check cable/connection
10 Mbps Half-Duplex
Device eth0:  hwaddr E0-B7-B1-23-60-D0, ipaddr not set, mask not set
        gateway not set, nameserver not set
*** command status = 0
```

Message from the dhcpd -

```
dhcpd: Sending on   Socket/fallback/fallback-net
dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.2.4-P2
dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
dhcpd: All rights reserved.
dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
dhcpd: Not searching LDAP since ldap-server, ldap-port and ldap-base-dn were not specified in the config file
dhcpd: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
dhcpd: Listening on LPF/p3p1/cc:b2:55:ba:b6:a4/10.0.0.0/24
dhcpd: Sending on   LPF/p3p1/cc:b2:55:ba:b6:a4/10.0.0.0/24
dhcpd: Sending on   Socket/fallback/fallback-net
```

Comment: Your device haven't agreed a physical connection on a cable connecting the device and the server, as it reported in the device log. Nothing can happen on a higher levels (TCP, DHCP) before the physical level is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to configure the DHCP. Here is the link to setup DHCP -

http://www.tune2wizard.com/dynamic-host-configuration-protocol-dhcp-networking/